# Workflow of login/signup system security for short-lived and persistent authentication

Tags: javascript, security, cookies, authorization, jwt

I understand that this question has been beaten to death because I've read a multitude of articles, questions and ideas about cookies and sessions and JWT's and so on.  Hopefully this question will not get closed in time to receive some feedback on how I'm trying to handle it.

The articles I settled on are

[Charles Miller's article, "Persistent Login Cookie Best Practice,"](https://www.programering.com/a/MDO0MzMwATA.html)

["Remember Me" - Long-Term Persistent Authentication](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/04/secure-authentication-php-with-long-term-persistence#title.2.1)

[Getting Token Authentication Right in a Stateless Single Page Application](https://medium.com/lightrail/getting-token-authentication-right-in-a-stateless-single-page-application-57d0c6474e3)

So here's my thinking:

- Non-logged in user visits site, basic session is created.

  - Keep track of user interactions (ex: adding items of interest to cart).
- Non-logged in user signs in or signs up.

  - If session exists, transfer session data as needed.
  - "selector:validator" as in article [2](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/04/secure-authentication-php-with-long-term-persistence#title.2.1) is created, selector put into JWT payload, validator into JWT header.  "selector:validator" saved in DB.
  - 'persistent' value is added to header as 0 or 1.
  - If "remember me" checked, JWT expiration set long-lived; if unchecked, JWT exp 15 min.
  - JWT is signed and split into two parts as in article [3](https://medium.com/lightrail/getting-token-authentication-right-in-a-stateless-single-page-application-57d0c6474e3): header and signature are sent as a long-lived secure http-only cookie, payload sent as a readable cookie with extremely short expiration.

The selector and validator should act like the series identifier and token from article [1](https://www.programering.com/a/MDO0MzMwATA.html).

Since this is not an SPA and I'm not using Angular, my thinking to work around the authentication Bearer header is whenever the page loads, get the readable cookie before it expires.  On subsequent page navigations, intercept the anchor click, set a cookie with the content from the readable cookie and proceed with that navigation. From my understanding, one major way to prevent CSRF is to set the Bearer header client side, so setting a cookie via Javascript would be the same strategy?

- Secured page request on the server, JWT reconstructed and checked whether expired.

  - If expired and 'persistent' = 0, redirect login.
  - If expired and 'persistent' = 1, check selector:validator against DB.
  - If selector and validator the same, issue and update DB with a new validator and sign a new JWT.
  - If only selector is the same, means cookie was used by another party and that party received a new validator.  Invalidate that selector completely and redirect to login.
  - If none match, redirect to login.

I understand this doesn't address XSS but if XSS is the main issue of the site, everything else goes out the window.

What are the problems with this workflow?  Some ways to improve?  Or remove altogether for another alternative?  I know this is a very broad and general question but I appreciate any feedback so I can stop wrestling with this problem in my head and get back to developing the site.  Thank you.

Edit: The reason for going with JWT is have the site somewhat stateless...not requiring a database lookup with every page request.  The lookup will only happen every 15 minutes when the JWT will be expired, regardless of persistent login or not.  I guess using regular cookies and putting the validator, userId and expiration of 15 minutes into a long-lived, secure http-only cookie would work as well without JWTs...